# 301 redirects for specific url's using Google App Engine(go)?

Tags: google-app-engine, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am using Google App Engine (go).. and I am looking to redirect https://www.ibikeride.com/scotland/comrie-croft-mountain-bike-trails/amp

to https://www.ibikeride.com/scotland/comrie-croft-mountain-bike-trails

I looked on google app engine docs on redirects but is more than pretty vague. I assume it is a redirect set up in the app.yaml file under handlers.

I actually want to redirect all files ending in "amp" to the same url structure without the amp
if there is a straightforward way of doing that and to avoid me doing a 100+ individual redirect.

For relevant info here is how my current handlers look NB(before attempting this). I have a few handlers to remove the '.html' from the end of url's (for specific categories) and also one at the end to redirect all files to secure 'https'

Any help appreciated

```
 handlers:

# this serves your static/some/path/<file>.html asset as /some/path/<file>.html
- url: /(england/.*\.html)$
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/england/.*\.html$

# this serves your static/some/path/<file>.html asset as /some/path/<file>
- url: /(england/.*)$
  static_files: static/\1.html
  upload: static/england/.*\.html$

# this serves your static/some/path/<file>.html asset as /some/path/<file>.html
- url: /(scotland/.*\.html)$
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/scotland/.*\.html$

# this serves your static/some/path/<file>.html asset as /some/path/<file>
- url: /(scotland/.*)$
  static_files: static/\1.html
  upload: static/scotland/.*\.html$

# this serves your static/some/path/<file>.html asset as /some/path/<file>.html

- url: /(wales/.*\.html)$
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/wales/.*\.html$

# this serves your static/some/path/<file>.html asset as /some/path/<file>
- url: /(wales.*)$
  static_files: static/\1.html
  upload: static/wales/.*\.html$

  # this serves your static/some/path/<file>.html asset as /some/path/<file>.html
- url: /(northern-ireland/.*\.html)$
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/orthern-ireland/.*\.html$

# this serves your static/some/path/<file>.html asset as /some/path/<file>
- url: /(northern-ireland.*)$
  static_files: static/\1.html
  upload: static/northern-ireland/.*\.html$

#redirect always to https 
- url: /.*
  script: auto
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the classification part `amp` at the end instead of the beginning I would suggest you to create a small service that redirects automatically.

For instance in app.yaml:

```yaml
handlers:
....
- url: /.*/amp
  script: main.go
```

And the code (main.go):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

type Handler struct{}


func (h *Handler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    uri := r.URL.Path
    length := len(uri)
    newUrl := uri[0:length-3] // Remove trailing amp
    http.Redirect(w, r, newUrl, http.StatusMovedPermanently)
    return
}

func main() {
    handler := new(Handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", handler)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that pretty intuitive. I'm using go112 and getting an error... INVALID_ARGUMENT: script field for handler '/.*/amp' must be set to 'auto' for runtime go112. How would you customise for this?